# Why can't var be used instead of let in ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, var, let

As per my knowledge we use `var` and `let` for variable declarations in javascript, the only difference being that `var` gets scoped to the current function, while `let` gets scoped to the current block. So it should work if I use `var` instead of `let` anywhere. But in the below code...

```
<li *ngFor="let fruit of fruits">
   {{ fruit}}
</li>
```

...if I use `var` it gives an error.

```
<li *ngFor="var fruit of fruits">
   {{ fruit}}
</li>
```

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: Parser
>   Error: Unexpected token var at column 1 in [var fruit of fruits] in
>   ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@4:4 ("

Can someone tell me why this occurs?

Comment: mmm, in angular render code, you cant do this...

Answer (score 13):

The expression you enter here is not really javascript (or typescript) but an angular expression.

There are other things you can do here that are not possible in JS or TS, like using pipes (`*ngFor="contacts | async"`).

Under the hood, this is just syntactic sugar for something like this:

```
 <ng-template ngFor let-contact [ngForOf]="contacts | async">
```

See https://toddmotto.com/angular-ngfor-template-element#ngfor-and-ng-template

Comment: but in typescript also `var` keyword is valid right?

Comment: Yes because any valid JS file is also a valid TS file (TS is a superset of JS).

Comment: these are two different ways to acheive *ngFor , but its not that '*ngFor' gets  converted into ng-template. Even the article you shared is great but hasnt mentioned such thing nor it is mentioned on the angular docs.

Comment: @manishkumar See the docs here: https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#inside-ngfor - it says "Angular transforms the `*ngFor` in similar fashion from asterisk (*) syntax through template attribute to <ng-template> element."

Comment: correct . transforms in similar fashion but isnt converted into the other and proceeds

Comment: @Vineesh It is a valid keyword, although you probably want to use `const` by default and `let` if mutation is necessary (and avoid `var`altogether). This way you profit from the saner semantics regarding scope. See https://github.com/Platypi/style_typescript#use-of-var-let-and-const

Answer (score 1):

Adding some details to the previous answer. I got some explanation for the usage of `let` with `*ngFor` in angular documentation

Link https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngfor

> The text assigned to *ngFor is the instruction that guides the
>   repeater process.
>
> *ngFor microsyntax The string assigned to *ngFor is not a template expression. It's a microsyntax — a little language of its own that
>   Angular interprets. The string "let hero of heroes" means:
>
> Take each hero in the heroes array, store it in the local hero looping
>   variable, and make it available to the templated HTML for each
>   iteration.
>
> Angular translates this instruction into a  around the
>   host element, then uses this template repeatedly to create a new set
>   of elements and bindings for each hero in the list.
>
> The let keyword before hero creates a template input variable called
>   hero. The ngFor directive iterates over the heroes array returned by
>   the parent component's heroes property and sets hero to the current
>   item from the array during each iteration.